# What is the theory behind loops? How can I select the entire edge loop in this case?

Tags: geometry, loop

### I fail to develop an intuition when it comes to the working of loops in blender

---

Geometry created from manipulating a cube, all the faces are quads

[image: Triangular kind of geometry created from manipulating a cube]

---

All the inner loops are continuous,

[image: All the inner loops are continuous]

---

in both the directions,

[image: vertical continuous loops]

---

### But look what happens when I select the outer loops

[image: Loop is not selected completely]

---

---

Can someone explain to me the logic behind this? Link to articles are highly welcomed.
(I select the edge loops using **alt key + left click**)
I am using Blender 2.81a on a macOS

Comment: Hello :). Those outer edges aren't actually loops. This answer by @Rekov explains it really well https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167163/

Comment: May be too simplified of an explanation but loops can only continue when quad faces are found on the way. If Tri is found, then the loop algorithm cannot decide to go left or right whereas if quads are found, it continues following the same "quad path"

Comment: Got it! 
It is so logical.